# How to include bootstrap 4 in an electron app

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, electron

I am able to figure out how to include bootstrap css but could not figure out how to include bootstrap js. I am trying to create some bootstrap tabs. Here is some sample code I wrote.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Coin Trader</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css">

  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link active" href="#profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">profile</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#buzz" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">buzz</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#references" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">references</a>
            </li>
          </ul>

          <!-- Tab panes -->
          <div class="tab-content">
            <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade in active" id="profile">...</div>
            <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="buzz">bbb</div>
            <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="references">ccc</div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
    <script>
      // You can also require other files to run in this process
      require('./renderer.js');
      window.$ = window.jquery = require("jquery");
      require("popper")
      require("bootstrap");
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

When I click on a tab it does not toggle. I think the issue is the bootstrap js is not being included right. I copied the tab code straight from bootstrap website.

Comment: Do you have a link to a repo that replicates the issue?

Comment: sorry, I have figured it out. Ill delete this question

Comment: If you've figured it out you should post an answer so others can benefit in the future. :)

Comment: https://techsparx.com/nodejs/electron/load-jquery-bootstrap.html may also help

Comment: also, [this project](https://github.com/patrickmoffitt/bootstrap-example) is demonstrates how to use Bootstrap and jQuery with Electron.

Answer (score 5):

I have figured out the solution. I included the wrong popper library. Instead of including `popper` include `popper.js`. Here is how I did it

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Coin Trader</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css">

  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link active" href="#profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">profile</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#buzz" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">buzz</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#references" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">references</a>
            </li>
          </ul>

          <!-- Tab panes -->
          <div class="tab-content">
            <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade in active" id="profile">...</div>
            <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="buzz">bbb</div>
            <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="references">ccc</div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
    <script>
      // You can also require other files to run in this process
      require('./renderer.js');
      window.$ = window.jquery = require("jquery");
      window.popper = require("popper.js");
      require("bootstrap");
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```